# Counting zeros of holomorphic function with constant absolute value on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in the complex plane bounded by $m+1$ number of disjoint analytic simple closed curves. Let $f$ be a non constant holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $\Omega \cup \partial \Omega$ with the property that 
$$|f(z)|=1,\;\;\text{for all }\; z \in \partial \Omega.$$

Then show that $f$ has at least $m+1$ zero (counting multiplicity) in $\Omega$.

I know the the proof if $\Omega$ is unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. But in general I am stuck in proving the result. I guess some kind of argument principle must give the answer, but I am not able to precisely pin it down. Any help will be great.

Comment: Maybe you should use the Riemann mapping theorem that states that open simply connected sets are biholomorphic to the unit disc?

Comment: But the domain mentioned above is not simply connected in general. Yes for simply connected i have an answer